# Can we use quantum physics to detect life outside our planet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, observers

I was watching a video about "delayed choice quantum eraser experiment", it shows how our knowledge about the system can change past events if they have not been measured yet.

I would like to ask about the thought experiment at [10:26](https://youtu.be/H6HLjpj4Nt4?t=626)

What if the astronomer chooses to use a screen-type of light projector that accompanies both sides of the surrounding space without focusing on a specific region, in such case, no one knows the path the photon took and he should get an interference pattern. But what if at the same time another astronomer chooses to use a binocular pariah, and discovered what path the electron choose? In such a case, the first astronomer should get a clumped pattern.

Now my question is, can an astronomer know based on the light pattern he sees that someone else is observing the same event that he does?

Can that someone be an observer from a different planet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you measure which path the photon takes involves interactions with the photon.  You have to operate on it.  Your observer on another planet could only observe it if something happened to scatter energy and/or information their way.  This would read as noise in the experiment.  You would not be able to determine the source of the effect, you would just see a less strong interference pattern.

When we talk about "observer" in QM, it inspires a conscious individual, but all that really matters for an "observation" is that the resulting interaction triggers something that can be thought of as "classical" (i.e. not quantum).  And when you get into decoherence theories, you find that this is not always an all-or-nothing effect.  You can have something that behaves mostly classical with *just* a little bit of quantum.